# how to change the text color when checking on elements

Tags: jquery

I would like to search in the HTML elements with classes to see if any element has the class `span1hrfor30mins` next to by an element that has the class `span1hr`, then change the color in each element in `row3` with a class `span1hr` to do for each text using with the loops.

Here's a sample of what the HTML is look like:

```
<div id="programe1" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_2 row2 span1hrfor30mins">Test program</div>
<div id="programe2" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_3 row3 span1hr">NCIS</div>
<div id="programe3" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_4 row4 span0hr">CBS Evening News With Scott Pelley</div>
<div id="programe4" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_5 row5 span1hr">NCIS: Los Angeles</div>
<div id="programe5" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_6 row6">Person of Interest</div>
<div id="programe6" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_2 row2 span1hrfor30mins">Twisted</div>
<div id="programe7" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_3 row3 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
<div id="programe8" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_4 row4 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
<div id="programe9" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_5 row5 span1hr">Twisted</div>
<div id="programe10" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_6 row6 span1hr">Pretty Little Liars</div>
<div id="programe11" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_2 row2 span1hr">CNN Newsroom</div>
<div id="programe12" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_3 row3 span1hr">Around the World</div>
<div id="programe13" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_4 row4 span0hr">CNN Newsroom</div>
<div id="programe14" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_5 row5 span2hr">CNN Newsroom</div>
<div id="programe15" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_6 row6 span1hr">The Lead With Jake Tapper</div>
```

In this case, since `NCIS` and `Pretty Little Liars` has a `span1hr` class, `Test program` and `Twisted` has a `span1hrfor30mins` class, I would like find on the sets for each element in `row2` with a class `span1hrfor30mins` next to by `row3` with a class `span1hr` to change the text in each `row3` while the other text in the `row2` remains unchanged.

I have tried the code like this, but it will search for every `row2` and `rows3` in the sets and it will only change the red texts in the `row2` when i want to change on each text in the `row3` with the class `span1hr` next to by the `row2` with a class `span1hrfor30mins`.

```
$('.span1hrfor30mins.row2').each(function (i, e) {
    $('+.span1hr.row3', e).length && $(e).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Here is an example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REjC5/6/

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use need to use the `next` method to target the elements you are looking for.

`next` gets the immediate sibling element that follows the element.

```
$('.span1hrfor30mins.row2').each(function (i, e) {
    $(this).next('.span1hr.row3').css('color', 'red');
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/REjC5/7/)**

Comment: @ChrisJohnson.. Glad to have helped :)